# Why does creating a UIImage from a JPEG and then exporting to a JPEG result in a file many times larger than the original?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uikit

I'm using XCode version 11.3.1 and Swift 4.2.

I have a JPEG file in my Assets.xcassets in XCode. It is 189 KB.

In Swift, I'm loading it into a UIImage like so:

```
let testImage = UIImage(named: "testImage")
```

Later on, I export this UIImage back to JPEG data:

```
let imageData = testImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
print(imageData.count)
```

Output:

```
792385
```

I expect that a `compressionQuality` of 1.0 would make the resulting JPEG the exact same size as the original. Instead, it has inflated it to 792 KB. The resulting image appears to be a perfectly valid JPEG file that doesnt have any white space added anywhere or anything like that.

By putting `compressionQuality` to 0.45, I get a JPEG that's just about the size of the original, though I don't understand why I need to compress at all to get back to the original size.

I understand that converting a local JPEG to a UIImage and then back to JPEG seems pointless, but this is the simplest way to reproduce an issue that's affecting a wider system.

Any ideas on why this increase in file size is happening are much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you create an UIImage object from a jpeg file you're decompressing and decoding the file so it is expected that the size increases and you need to apply compression again if/when saving the file. This also happens in an image editing program like Photoshop, open a jpeg saved with less than 1 (or 100% in PS) and then directly save it with 100% quality and it will be larger than the original